# AWS SQS - CDK - how to create topic filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm able to create an SQS queue + lambda function and connect them via trigger/subscription.

**How can I create a topic filter via CDK?**

I'm able to create the topic, lambda, and trigger / subscription like so:

```
const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, 'OurSqsQueue', {
  queueName: 'OurSQSQueue',
});
const lambdaFunction = new lambda.Function(this,'test', {
       code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('src'),
       handler: index.lambdaHandler,
       functionName: 'test',
       runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
     });

const eventSource = new lambdaEventSources.SqsEventSource(queue);
lambdaFunction.addEventSource(eventSource);
```

[According to the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-filtering.html) Amazon SQS topic subscriber receives every message published to the topic. To receive a subset of the messages, a subscriber must assign a filter policy to the topic subscription.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambda event filtering for SQS, DynamoDB, and Kinesis event sources was [announced last month](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/aws-lambda-event-filtering-amazon-sqs-dynamodb-kinesis-sources), but is not yet supported in the CDK.  There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/17874) on github.

In the meantime, we can use the [escape hatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) to
set filters on the underlying `CfnEventSourceMapping` Construct.

Here's a minimal working example:

```js
export class LambdaEventFilterEscape extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const func = new lambda.Function(this, 'MyFunction', {
      code: new lambda.InlineCode('exports.handler = async (event) => console.log(event)'),
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
      handler: 'index.handler',
    });

    const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, 'MyQueue');
    queue.grantConsumeMessages(func);

    const source = new lambda.EventSourceMapping(this, 'EventSourceMapping', {
      target: func,
      eventSourceArn: queue.queueArn,
    });

    // escape hatch
    const cfnSouce = source.node.defaultChild as lambda.CfnEventSourceMapping;

    cfnSouce.addPropertyOverride('FilterCriteria', {
      // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html#filtering-syntax
      Filters: [{ Pattern: `{\"body\": { \"Data\" : { \"Name\": [\"Zaphod\", \"Ford\" ] }}}` }],
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AWS SQS and SNS are different servies. SQS has queues, SNS has topics.

I'm assuming you're indeed talking about SQS. Filtering for SQS queues was impossible until two weeks ago, when [this was added](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/aws-lambda-event-filtering-amazon-sqs-dynamodb-kinesis-sources/).

The support for this feature has not been implemented in CDK yet.

I am not completely sure whether CloudFormation supports this at all at this point, but you can try working with the low-level [CfnEventSourceMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.CfnEventSourceMapping.html) resource, here are the [CloudFormation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html) for it.

Answer (score 0):

AWS recently released a new version of CDK where you can define filter using the `filters` prop in the Event Source Mappping.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_event_sources.SqsEventSourceProps.html#filters

For example:

```
sqs_event_source = lambda_es.SqsEventSource(
            queue=queue,
            batch_size=1,
            filters=[
                {
                    "pattern": '{"messageAttributes": {"myAttr": {"stringValue": ["test"]}}}'
                }
            ]
        )
```